# using class of a module in another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm creating a gem:

```
module Core
  require "lib/doctor"
  require "lib/slot"
end

module Core
  class Doctor
    def message
      puts Slot.message
    end
  end
end

module Core
  class Slot
    def message
      return "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

If I use the gem I obtain:

```
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Core::Doctor::Slot
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html

Comment: Did you sort this out?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from your error, ruby is trying to load the constant `Slot` in the context of `Core::Doctor`. But, you want `Slot` in the context of `Core`. So, try:

```
module Core
  class Doctor
    def message
      puts Core::Slot.message
    end
  end
end
```

Also, here:

```
puts Core::Slot.message
```

you're trying to call `message` as a class method. However, here:

```
module Core
  class Slot
    def message
      return "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

you're defining `message` as an instance method.

If you want `message` to be a class method, you'll need to do:

```
module Core
  class Slot
    def self.message
      return "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
module Core
  class Slot
    class << self
      def message
        return "Hello World"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(depending on your preference). If you want keep `message` as an instance method, then you'll need to do:

```
puts Core::Slot.new.message
```